# orthogonality in Hardy space on bidisk

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $f$ is an arbitrary element in the Hardy space $H^{2}(\mathbb{D}^2)$, such that f is orthogonal to the set $\Big\{z^{m}\Big(\frac{(w-\alpha)}{(1-\overline{\alpha}w)}\Big)^{n} \Big\}$, for all non-negative integers$~~$ $m,n\geq 0$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{D}$ is a fixed value. Does this imply $f\equiv 0$?

The case for $\alpha=0$ is obvious.

Comment: Also since 2-norm of each element of the given set is 1, does this imply the above mentioned set forms an orthonormal basis of $H^{2}\mathbb{D}^{2}$?

Comment: For your extra question, the answer is yes. Let $H$ be a Hilbert space. If $B \subset H$ is a family of orthonormal vectors such that $B^{\perp} = \{0\}$ then the elements of $B$ form an orthonormal basis of $H$. Indeed, such a $B$ is a basis if and only if $\overline{\mathrm{vect}(B)} = H$. But $\overline{\mathrm{vect(B)}}^{\perp} = B^{\perp}$ and $H = \overline{\mathrm{vect(B)}} \oplus^{\perp} \overline{\mathrm{vect}(B)}^{\perp}$. Thus $H = \overline{\mathrm{vect}(B)}$.

Comment: Thanks halbaroth, but the main concern is why does this set spans $H^{2}(\mathbb{D}^{2})$?

Comment: I think the first step is to show that $w^j$ (Defined on the unit disk) can be approximated by linear combination of $\left(\frac{z-a}{1-\bar{a}z}\right)^n$ Uniformly on disk. If we have this it follows that $z^iw^j$ can be uniformly approximated by your set. That should complete the proof.

Comment: Thanks WhoknowsWho, did you mean converging $z^{j}$ for all $j\geq 0$. So if I find one sequence of the linear combination which converge to $z$ then i can find it for other exponent also.